# creating multiple arrays from a function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to create a seperate array each time this function runs, currently it seems to write over the function every time it runs.

How would i go about doing this? any help appreciated, thanks.

```
<script>
var a = [[4,1,2],[3,7,9],[2,3,5]];

function swap(x,y,m,n){
    var src=x;
    var dest = y;
    var tmp = a[x][y];
    a[x][y] = a[m][n];
    a[m][n] = tmp;
    newArray = new Array(a);
    return newArray;
}

var tmp1 = new Array(swap(1,0,0,0));
var tmp2 = new Array(swap(1,0,2,0));
document.write(tmp1 + "<br>" + tmp2 + " <br>" + a);
</script>
```

Comment: Clone the array before modifying it. Basically you could just change the order inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable "b" inside the function, that works as a temporary copy of array "a", precventing it to be changed during the function.

```
   <script>
    var a = [[4,1,2],[3,7,9],[2,3,5]];

    function swap(x,y,m,n){
        var b = a;
        var src=x;
        var dest = y;
        var tmp = b[x][y];
        b[x][y] = b[m][n];
        b[m][n] = tmp;
        newArray = new Array(b);
        return newArray;
    }

    var tmp1 = new Array(swap(1,0,0,0));
    var tmp2 = new Array(swap(1,0,2,0));
    document.write(tmp1 + "<br>" + tmp2 + " <br>" + a);
    </script>
```